# Calculate Business Days For Different Countries

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm

I want to calculate the business days between two days on my asp.net webpage. I have a country table. When user select dates from calenders and select the country from listbox, number of business days will be displayed (different countries should have different weekends).

I'm using bit (boolean) datatype for the daysofweek in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`end date - start date - weekends - holidays`
where weekends and holidays are the variables. but that shouldn't be difficult to determine if the dates are kept in the database.